# Does Ubuntu 20.04 support Amazon workspace client?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, amazon-workspaces

Getting the following error after login in successfully.

[UnSupported Workspace Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srqMU.jpg)

Comment: yeah i faced the same